# How to assign relevance to categories in solr?

Tags: json, indexing, solr

I'm usin Solr in a project where all data are stored in a json file.

the data has the following structure

```
{
  url: "url.com",
  title: "the title",
  content: [
    "content 1",
    "content 2",
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to add relevance to the title over the content because currently, the algorithm doesn't discriminate between title, content, etc...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the (e)dismax parses, you can give each field a distinct weight when you're querying by [using the query fields argument](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+DisMax+Query+Parser#TheDisMaxQueryParser-Theqf(QueryFields)Parameter) (`qf`).

The syntax is `qf=title^20 content^10 url`, which gives any hits in title 20 times the weight of hits in url and twice the weight of hits in content. Adjust the weights according to what's useful for your application.